# How to clean a dusty television screen?

Tags: cleaning, technology, dust

The screen of my LCD television often gets dusty. I've tried cleaning it with a microfiber cloth, but it just pushes the dust into the corners of the screen. How can I more efficiently clean the screen from dust?

Answer (score 5):

First dip a microfiber cloth in water (preferably distilled water so that you don't coat the screen with any impurities), and then squeeze out the excess water.  Then use it to wipe the screen.  The fact that it's damp will result in it picking up all the dust, instead of pushing the dust into the corners.

After you've wiped off all the dust, you may have a lot of dried water spots/streaks all over the screen.  Take a dry microfiber cloth and wipe off all the water spots/streaks.  After that, the screen should be free of dust and water spots/streaks.

Answer (score 2):

In that situation, I usually turn off the TV, unplug it from the wall, and then use a Swiffer duster.

http://www.swiffer.com/products/swiffer-dusters

Any dust that's left is removed with a dampened-then-squeezed-dry microfiber cloth.

Comment: It's easer to see the marks with the screen switched off.  :)